# How can I access my Azure Functions' logs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The logs in my log stream associated with my Azure Function App have changed and I believe the logs are going somewhere else where I'm not sure exactly how to access them. Here's a snapshot of the new messages I'm receiving:

[image]

Would anyone know why my logs changed to be like this and how/where I might be able to access my logs from my running function (seems to running fine)?

Comment: Whatever the logs coming when running the function app, you can see in application insights in the form of metrics, or you can see in storage account associated with that function app!

Comment: Check [one of my workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703835/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-set-up-logging-for-an-azure-function/70707231#70707231) to see the logs in the Azure, if it helps to!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Ah, thank you! I checked out your workaround and realized that there are 2 different type of logs. My function somehow got switched to FileSystem Logs, instead of being on Application Insights Logs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While running the Azure Function, you can see the File System Logs in the Logs Console of the Test/Run Page or Log Stream under Monitoring in the left index menu of the Function App.

[image: AzF-FileSystemLogsRepro]

**File System Logs <- Log Stream <- Monitoring (Left Index Menu) of the Function App**:

[image: LogStreamMenu]

All these File System Logs you can see in the Storage Account associated with that Azure Function App.
**`Storage Account > File Shares (under Data Storage) > Your Function App > LogFiles > Application > Functions > Host`**

[image: FileSystemLogFilesinHost]

In the path of **`Storage Account > File Shares (under Data Storage) > Your Function App > LogFiles > Application > Functions > Function > Your Function Name >`** You can see the console result (Application Logs - Execution results/failed result/error data) of the function.

[image: AppLogsinFunction]

Same Files/Logs you can see in Kudu Explorer along with the traces (but it gives minimum information from your requests and response logs) as shown in the first Gif Image.

Comment: this appears to only apply to scripted web functions, not compiled - for those interested in logs for compiled.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me like Microsoft has since disabled log streaming on function apps as shown below.

[image]

The only way I have been able to see live logs is a log tail on the Azure CLI as below.

> az webapp log tail --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name
> $FUNCTIONNAME

Comment: I've been able to access the Azure Function log stream in VSCode using their Azure Functions extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions