# How to send azure function metrics to an app insight where the Local authentication is disabled

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, appinsights

I'm currently struggling with Azure Function logs.

I'm trying to redirect all the default logs to the app insight, including metrics and so on.

Here is my architecture:

- an App Insight, where the Local authentication is disabled
- an azure function, which is "Monitoring Metrics Publisher" on the App Insight

I found the following code on the Azure Microsoft documentation :

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential

from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
from opencensus.trace.samplers import ProbabilitySampler
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
tracer = Tracer(
    exporter=AzureExporter(credential=credential, connection_string="InstrumentationKey=<your-instrumentation-key>;IngestionEndpoint=<your-ingestion-endpoint>"),
    sampler=ProbabilitySampler(1.0)
)
```

It let me create a tracer. But it does not redirect any metrics.

The second code I found let me add a handler, but without including the ManagedIdentityCredential.

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# TODO: replace the all-zero GUID with your instrumentation key.
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)
```

I try to merge both snippets of code. The function is running but it doesn't send any metrics.

My goal is to get all azure logs I get before disabling the app insight Local authentication.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you see the microsoft doc for Python code sample, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python#instrument-with-opentelemetry ?

Comment: How do you conclude that it doesn't send any metrics - where are you seeing? You need to view under `Logs (analytics)` blade, refer this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#view-your-data-with-queries

Comment: Have you got this to work. I am having the same issue and I am not able to see any logs in App Insight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the function, then you can see the Live Logs captured on the console of the "**Run+Test**" Window and also on the Log Stream under Monitoring of Function App Menu in the Azure Portal.

Also, you can see the logs stored in the Storage Account that is specific to each function in your Azure Function Apps as I have shown in one of my previous workarounds SO #[71566402](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566402/16630138).

As @*AnandSowmithiran* suggested an [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python#instrument-with-opentelemetry) that you want to specify the Instrumentation Key/libraries for collecting the logs in Telemetry data automatically for the Azure Functions that uses the Stacks/Language Runtimes such as .NET, Node JS, Python and also you can view the Log Analytics Portal for the detailed app insights Logs. Azure Function App > Menu > Monitoring - Logs Window --> you can see all the existing queries or write your own Kusto Query to fetch all types of logs.