# Saving logs in Azure Functions

Tags: logging, azure-functions

After reading a lot of answers and tutorials regarding logging Azure Functions I could not see the log history.

I am confused regarding saving logs in blob storage and queues.

I configured the application insights and also made a rule in diagnostics that should save the logs in storage but it doesn't work.

I can see the function logs in live, but I want log files in the storage to see what happended in previous http requests.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you have configured Application Insights, that should already do it. Have you tried to query the `Requests` and `Traces` table in AppInsights?

Comment: @silent The query result is empty

Comment: @Alex did you find any solution for this ? Have been struggling on this as well , I can see only the history of http executions while I am interested in the logs from the code run

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the Function App, then the logs automatically get stored in the associated Storage Account File Share by Azure Functions Core Tools Runtime Environment as mentioned in this SO Issue #[71560901](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71560901).

Also, you can query in the Function App Logs Panel using the keywords `requests`, `traces` as given by the user @*Silent*.

To get the Function App Logs in Blob Storage, you have to follow below steps before running the Function:

1. Go to **Azure Portal** > **Function App** > **Diagnostic Settings** > Select the **category of logs** required and send it to Storage Account as shown below:

*I have selected my storage account which is associated with my function app:*

[image]

[image]

After running the Function for several times, a folder got created in the Blob Storage Containers which contains the subfolders i.e., subscription id, resource group name, function app name, year, month, day, hour, minute.
It shows the logs of the time period in which the function has run/executed.

**Result**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wrote in the question that I configured the diagnostics section and it is not working. I don't  need to see the http requests, I want to see the logs that I wrote calling the ILogger.LogDebug in the function itself

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to query traces as follows

1. Navigate to function > application insights > logs
2. Query traces table as follows

   traces
   | where severityLevel >= 1 and customDimensions["Category"] == "Function.<function_name>.User" and operation_Name=="<function_name>"

[image]
Note

- The details about severity level is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet)
- For detailed explanation view [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/get-started-queries)