# Why can not I see logs in Azure Function app?

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am working on Azure Function App (Python on Linux), but I am unable to view the logs.

When I go to web portal to the Function App - tab Log Stream, the page never loads. There is just a spinning circle.

The same happens when I open the Function itself and go to "*Code + Test*". The console says, `Connecting to Application Insights...`, but it never loads.

The Function App is not linked to "*Application Insights*". But to my understanding I do not need to create Application Insights resource to just see simple logs. Or am I wrong?

I am quite new to Azure, so I appreciate any help!

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560901/how-can-i-access-my-azure-functions-logs#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,5,has%20since%20disabled%20log%20streaming%20on%20function%20apps%20as%20shown%20below.,-The%20only%20way) post one of the users says that log streaming has been limited, so I assume that I am facing the similar issue. I have tried using VS Code extension Azure to stream logs, but it also requires Application Insights. `Error: You must configure Application Insights to stream logs on Linux Function Apps`.

**Do I really have to create Application Insights resource?** (It's complicated for me to create new resource due to corporate structure)

Edit:

As requested I am adding the code. I don't think that the issue is with the code itself. I am unable to view any logging page in Azure web portal as well as I am unable to stream logs to VS Code. The issues occurs even before running the code.

I am expecting to see at least something. Any print or log statement, or even error message. But I am unable to anything.

Also [here](https://imgur.com/a/40lAeaF) here are some screenshots from Azure Portal and the issues I am facing.

```
""" function_app.py """
import azure.functions as func
import logging
@app.route(route="http_trigger_test")
def http_trigger_test(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Code finished", status_code=200)


""" requirements.txt """
# DO NOT include azure-functions-worker in this file
# The Python Worker is managed by Azure Functions platform
# Manually managing azure-functions-worker may cause unexpected issues
azure-functions


""" http_trigger_test.json """
{
    "name": "http_trigger_test",
    "entryPoint": "http_trigger_test",
    "scriptFile": "function_app.py",
    "language": "python",
    "functionDirectory": "/home/site/wwwroot",
    "bindings": [
        {
            "direction": "IN",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "name": "req",
            "authLevel": "ANONYMOUS",
            "route": "http_trigger_test"
        },
        {
            "direction": "OUT",
            "type": "http",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you just share your code what you have tried and which trigger you are taking and deployed to azure function app? and what type of logs you are expecting? please share more details about your issue?

Comment: Did you deployed the http trigger function successfully into portal?

Comment: @Pavan Yes, the function is sucessfully deployed to the portal

Comment: Did you enable application insights while creating function app?

Comment: No, I didn't. That's basically my question (should have been more clear). Do I need application insights?
I thought that I don't need it to see just simple logs. That it is only required to advanced analysis. @Pavan

Comment: I have deployed http trigger function into linux function app. its running perfectly in portal. check [this](https://i.imgur.com/wrMcruH.png)

Comment: Did you link the app to Application Insights? @Pavan

Comment: I have just enabled application insights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256706/discussion-between-pavan-and-herdek550).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Function App is not linked to "*Application Insights*". But to my understanding I do not need to create Application Insights resource to just see simple logs. Or am I wrong?

For getting simple logs or complex logs will definitely use application insights, there is no other option to get logs. Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77904488/21525734) for further clarification.

I have created http trigger function by using vs code and it ran successfully.

[image]

I have deployed the above function into azure portal. check below:

[image]

Before enable the application insights, when I tried to visit logs getting like below:

[image]

I was enabled the application insights and rans the function successfully in portal. check below:

[image]

I was able to see the logs after enabled the application insights. check below:

**Output:**

[image]