# Azure Function requires ApplicationInsight logging configured - why?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For the default Azure Function project created by Visual Studio for .NET 8, it initializes host.json with:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the `applicationInsights` part, the program doesn't run. It starts up, but the http trigger is never executed. Why?

In addition, if I add to host.json the following, it does not create the File or Console logging providers. Why?

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning",
            "LouisHowe": "Trace",
            "ThirdPartyServices": "Debug",
            "CommonUtilities": "Debug",
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
        },

        "File": {
            "Path": "C:/temp/log-function/{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
            "Interval": "day",
            "FlushInterval": 1
        },

        "Console": {
            "FormatterName": "simple",
            "FormatterOptions": {
                "SingleLine": true,
                "IncludeScopes": true,
                "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss ",
                "UseUtcTimestamp": true,
                "JsonWriterOptions": {
                    "Indented": true
                }
            }
        },

        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding **`Application Insights`** setting is **`mandatory`** as it contains the configuration Options for all the Functions in your Function App, Also applicationInsights sets the logging and you can customize the logging by changing your **`host.json`** code:-

In the **Program.cs** the **ApplicationInsights** **service** is called  by default:-

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Also, According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) on **`host.json 2x version`** Console logging will only work when the Function is not running in debugging mode. Also, When you run your Function locally, The default Console is not used, Azure Function host will start its own host and console to run the Function and you cannot control that console as it is triggered by Function host:-

I tried using below, host.json file and it gave me the debug logs of traces successfully, Refer below:-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.MyFunction": "Trace",
      "default": "Debug"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}
```

***Local Output:-***

[image]

File option is not supported locally as well as in Azure Functions, Only the parameters in the MS Document above are supported. You can use ***fileLoggingMode*** which will give log files when run in Azure Function App. Also, Azure Function will generate log files by default.

```
"File": {
            "Path": "C:/temp/log-function/{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
            "Interval": "day",
            "FlushInterval": 1
}
```

I published the Function in function app and accessed log files from the option below:-

```
C:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. A couple of follow-up questions: 1. How do I configure the file logging exactly? My Windows does not have the C:\home folder. Granted I can create it, but what exactly is it looking for as to where to write the logs? 2. I want to use my Blob logging provider, both locally and on Azure. How do I get it to use it? TIA.

Comment: 1. How do I configure the file logging exactly? My Windows does not have the C:\home folder. Granted I can create it, but what exactly is it looking for as to where to write the logs? >> By default host.json settings won't write logs in any of your windows folder as that is not the parameter that is supported. You need to make changes in your Function1.cs to write the logs to the Local file, Something like this-

Comment: public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Before logging");
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            _logger.LogInformation("After logging");

            // Use C:\local\temp for logging in this example
            var logFilePath = "C:\\local\\temp\\function-log.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logFilePath, "Log content written to C:\\local\\temp.");

Comment: 2. I want to use my Blob logging provider, both locally and on Azure. How do I get it to use it?  >> On Azure it will be logged by default in the same place given in my answer, For local environment you need to add it via your Function1.cs code as that is not the option available for now